# Nested list manipulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I have a a nested lists containing a product name, product id and product data (another list). I want to create a list of dictionaries with unique names and product ids and join the lists of data related to the name and id variable.

My data looks like:

```
print(x)
[(14, 'netflix', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), (14, 'netflix', [7, 8, 9, 10]),(15,'tv',
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), (15, 'tv', [7, 8, 9]), (16, 'radio', [1, 2, 3, 4]), 
(16, 'radio', [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

I want to convert my data to look like:

```
x = [{'product_id':x[0], 'product': row[1], 'values':row[2]} for row in x]

#or for this example

x = [{'product_id':14, 'product':'netflix', 'values':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}, 
     {'product_id':15, 'product': 'tv',     'values':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}, 
     {'product_id':16, 'product': 'radio',  'values':[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]}]
```

I know I can loop through the nested list using:

```
for inner_l in x:
    for item in x:
        print(item)
```

But I am unsure of how to manipulate these lists to create my desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution to my problem which involves setting dictionary keys using `.setdefalut()` and joining strings:

```
new_dict = dict()

for i in x:
    new_dict.setdefault(i[0], '')
    new_dict[x[0]] += ',' + i[1][1:-1]

for prod in new_dict:
    new_dict[prod] = new_dict[prod][1:]
```

Answer (score 7):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
data = [(14, 'netflix', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), (14, 'netflix', [7, 8, 9, 10]),(15,'tv',[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), (15, 'tv', [7, 8, 9]), (16, 'radio', [1, 2, 3, 4]),(16, 'radio', [1, 2, 3, 4]) ]
keys = ['product_id', 'product', 'values']
result = {}   
for product_id, product, values in data:
    if product_id not in result:
        result[product_id] = dict(zip(keys, (product_id, product, values)))
    else:
        result[product_id]["values"].extend(values)
print(list(result.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'product': 'netflix',
  'product_id': 14,
  'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]},
 {'product': 'tv', 'product_id': 15, 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]},
 {'product': 'radio', 'product_id': 16, 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]}]
```

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for, I want to join all of the value lists. See me example output above. Thanks

Comment: @WilliamGoodwin. Sorry missed that. Updated snippet

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the inner tuples by the first item, i.e the `product_id` (sorting might be needed if they are not ordered, and append to a list as a dictionary combining both lists in the last position:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter as ig

keys = ['product_id', 'product', 'values']   
out = []

for _, ((*a,b), (*_,c)) in groupby(sorted(l, key=ig(0)), key=ig(0)):
    out.append(dict(zip(keys, a + [b+c])))
```

---

```
print(out)

[{'product': 'netflix', 'product_id': 14, 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]},
 {'product': 'tv', 'product_id': 15, 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]},
 {'product': 'radio', 'product_id': 16, 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]}]
```

Comment: Gets me 99% of the way!! Thanks! The output values should just be one list i.e. remove square brackets.

Comment: But they are, aren't they? @WilliamGoodwin You mean the lists in values right?

Comment: Pretty much but for 'netflix' for example I have data = '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6][7, 8, 9, 10]' I am looking for '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]'

Comment: I'm getting the right output @WilliamGoodwin try with the update

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged `pandas`, use `pd.DataFrame` constructor with column naming then use `groupby` with `sum` and covert to dictionary using `to_dict` with `orient='records'`:

```
import pandas as pd

x = [(14, 'netflix', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), (14, 'netflix', [7, 8, 9, 10]),(15,'tv',
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), (15, 'tv', [7, 8, 9]), (16, 'radio', [1, 2, 3, 4]), 
(16, 'radio', [1, 2, 3, 4])]

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['product_id','product', 'values'])

df.groupby(['product_id','product'], as_index=False)[['values']]\
  .sum()\
  .to_dict(orient='records')
```

Output:

```
[{'product_id': 14,
  'product': 'netflix',
  'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]},
 {'product_id': 15, 'product': 'tv', 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]},
 {'product_id': 16, 'product': 'radio', 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]}]
```

Comment: and `groupby('product_id')` :) I made the same mistake before

Answer (score 0):

You could use `defaultdict` this way, where `x` is the input data:

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(dict)

for h in x:
  k = h[1]
  res[k]['id'] = h[0]
  res[k]['product'] = h[1]
  if 'values' in res[k]:
    res[k]['values'] += h[2]
  else:
    res[k]['values'] = h[2]
```

Then you can extract from `res`:

```
print(dict(res))
#=> {'netflix': {'id': 14, 'product': 'netflix', 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}, 'tv': {'id': 15, 'product': 'tv', 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]}, 'radio': {'id': 16, 'product': 'radio', 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]}}

print(list(res.values()))
#=> [{'id': 14, 'product': 'netflix', 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}, {'id': 15, 'product': 'tv', 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]}, {'id': 16, 'product': 'radio', 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]}]
```

---

Or a nested `defaultdict`:

```
res = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict, {'product': None, 'id': None, 'values': []}))

for h in x:
  k = h[1]
  res[k]['id'] = h[0]
  res[k]['product'] = h[1]
  res[k]['values'] += h[2]
```

Which results in:

```
print(list(res.values()))
#=> [defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'product': 'netflix', 'id': 14, 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 7, 8, 9, 10]}), defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'product': 'tv', 'id': 15, 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9]}), defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'product': 'radio', 'id': 16, 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]})]

print([ dict(val) for val in res.values()])
#=> [{'product': 'netflix', 'id': 14, 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 7, 8, 9, 10]}, {'product': 'tv', 'id': 15, 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9]}, {'product': 'radio', 'id': 16, 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]}]
```